# Formik and React-Select - When submitting form fails, select dropdown does not maintain proper value

Tags: reactjs, react-select, formik

I am using `React`, `Formik`, and `react-select`. I am having trouble with a dropdown select field for country.

Before I submit the form, I can see that the form has both a value and a label:

```
console.log(this.props.values.billing_information_attributes.address_attributes.country )
```

returns this `{value: "United States", label: "United States"}`

After I submit the form and the post request responds with a failure (this is a desired failure for test purposes), all other forms retain their values with the exception of this dropdown. Now the same `console.log` returns only `"United States"`

For the dropdown to work, it needs to be provided an object in the format mentioned before `{value: "United States", label: "United States"}` or the dropdown appears blank. Obviously, I could instrument a work around and set the field value again using `setFieldValue`, but I feel I am missing something in regards to the Formik lifecycle. One other important thing to mention is that before I send the post request I am modifying the data I send to the server and only sending the value of the country, not the entire value and label object, like this:

```
newParams["billing_information_attributes"]["address_attributes"]["country"] =
params["billing_information_attributes"]["address_attributes"]["country"].value
```

Here is my post request:

```
handleSubmit = (params, actions) => {
    Stripe.card.createToken(
      {
        number: params.card_number,
        cvc: params.security_id,
        exp_month: params.exp_month,
        exp_year: params.exp_year,
        address_zip: params.billing_information_attributes.address_attributes.postal_code
      },
      (status, response) => {
        params.stripe_card_token = response.id
        axios
          .request("/order/complete", {
            method: "patch",
            data: {
              order: modifiedParams(params, "checkoutForm"),
              authenticity_token: this.props.authenticity_token,
              agree_to_terms: params.agree_to_terms,
              save_new_card: params.save_new_card,
              saved_cards: params.saved_cards.value
            }
          })
          .then(({ data }) => {
            if (data.success) {
              actions.resetForm()
              actions.setStatus({ message: data.message })
              window.location.replace("/order/" + data.order_id)
            } else {
              actions.setErrors({ server: data.errors })
              actions.setStatus({ message: data.message})
              console.log(data)
            }
            actions.setSubmitting(false)
            document.querySelector(".flashMsg").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            actions.setSubmitting(false)
            actions.setErrors({ server: ["Cannot submit form at the moment. Please try again."] })
            document.querySelector("body").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
          })
      }
    )
  }
```

Can anyone help figure out why the value of `this.props.values.billing_information_attributes.address_attributes.country` changes from `{value: "United States", label: "United States"}` to simply `United States` after submit and the post request responds with a failure? Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind providing a minimal code example showing your problem using a service like [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)?

Comment: Your questions is very hard to understand, `Can anyone help figure out why the values of this field change after submit?` I can't understand how they change, please explain better

Comment: @Vencovsky I edited my question with a better explanation. See if this makes sense to you now. I had someone reply on the `formik` issues page https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1452 confirming this was also happening to him. I am thinking it must be a bug in `formik`.